# Gdb prints no stack

Tags: c++, gdb

So my program compiles and prints the right values, but then when I use gdb it prints inferrior 1 process(...) exited normally. And then upon writing bt it prints back "no stack". Is this an error or an indication that everything works?

Comment: I am sorry , my bad. But because it is the first time I use GDB is it ok or not?

Comment: It's OK. What kind of stack do you expect after process termination?

Comment: You may be using GDB incorrectly, launch the gdb on the executable (`gdb ./my_exe`), then `start`, then `s` (step). You will find it easier to debug your application if you compile with debug symbols and reduce optimisation level.

Comment: @Mansoor I ued the command  gdb ./exe  then i pressed run and then bt

Comment: If you `run` without setting any breakpoints, your program will run to completion. So when you try `bt`, the process has already exited, there is no stack to view.